# Date Comparision doesn't work fine in openerp7

Tags: odoo

I have 2 dates (from date and to date) in hand. I would like to know if there's another record in the table that falls on the same range. I use openerp search function to do that

below is my code. Kindly see if my date search with operator <= is correct and is there anything that i wrongly understood.

```
exist_ids = self.search(cr, uid, [('partner_id','=',customer),('sys_conf_name','ilike',sys_conf_name.strip()),('contract_start_date','<=',cont_start_date),('contract_end_date','>=',cont_end_date)])
if exist_ids:
      raise osv.except_osv(_('Error!!'), "Already there exist a Contract for the same customer, same product and the same date range!!")
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

try to pass the datetime object of that from and to date and not the string